# How to bulk copy custom fields between custom posts?

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy, custom-field

I have a CPT called (services) that has a custom field with name of (price), and there is also a custom taxonomy which has a CPT with a name (catalog) that has also a custom field with a name of (price).

it is meant for a catalog post to have it's service price, and i already added the services prices. Now i want to bulk copy the (price) custom field in services to the (price) custom field in (Catalog) in bulk, How can i do this?

To be mentioned, posts has the same names

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is pretty complex. Without getting into your system it's pretty tough to solve it. For your case I would prefer to run database query but it's seemed too complex to me. By the way here I've tried to write a simple `PHP` script-

```
function the_dramatist_get_post_by_title( $page_title, $post_type ='post' ) {
    global $wpdb;
    $post = $wpdb->get_var( $wpdb->prepare( "SELECT ID FROM $wpdb->posts WHERE post_title = %s AND post_type= %s", $page_title, $post_type));
    if ( $post )
        return $post;

    return null;
}

function the_dramatist_bulk_copy_c_fields() {
    $c_posts = wp_list_pluck( get_posts(array(
        'post_type'=>'catalog',
        'posts_per_page' => -1
    )), 'ID' );

    foreach($c_posts as $c){
        $title = get_the_title( $c );
        $s_id = the_dramatist_get_post_by_title( $title, 'services');
        $meta_value = get_post_meta( $s_id, 'price', true );
        add_post_meta( $c, 'price', $meta_value );
    }
    return true;
}

add_action('init', 'the_dramatist_bulk_copy_c_fields');
```

Run the script only once. I haven't got the chance to test it. So please test it before using it in production.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks @the_dramatist, but unfortunately it didn't work

Comment: you answer makes sense and i don't know why it didn't work , i had to change the post type name to the real ones `td_catalog` and `td_services` but nothing changed

Comment: @MohamedOmar, Can you please share your database ? I'm planning to write a SQL query to do your job. Without seeing your database it's pretty tough. So I need your database.

Comment: Here is a download link of database (works on localhost): https://www.mediafire.com/?3vxbbvdszy0xh5q

Comment: please use the `product` post type with `catalog` and forget about `services` . the `product` also has the same name

Comment: I've not understood. Can you please clarify it a little bit. You've question about two different post types and now you are saying that those are same. That has not meant sense to me. @MohamedOmar

Comment: Yes I have three different post types according to the theme , these three types has the same posts names ... and what made me choose the product to query against is that it can be easily found on the database. So now please you can query a custom field named (regular price) from poducts and copy it to (price) from catalog. Thats it ... same task with different post types